# Google Searches With no Results

Tags: open-ended

What is the shortest string of letters that yields no results in a Google search?
When answering, please use the [NATO alphabet](https://www.nyc-arecs.org/pa.pdf) in order to prevent the string from becoming a search result.
[Scoring](https://www3.nd.edu/~busiforc/handouts/cryptography/letterfrequencies.html):

```
E - 57            N - 34            P - 16            K - 6  
A - 43            S - 29            M, H - 15         V - 5  
R - 39            L - 28            G - 13            X, Z, J, Q - 1  
I - 38            C - 23            B - 11  
O - 37            U - 19            F, Y - 9  
T - 35            D - 17            W - 7
```

The best string that I could come up with is:
**E**cho, **B**ravo, **Q**uebec, **E**cho, **T**ango, **X**-ray, **E**cho, **A**lpha (262 pt)

When you enter strings below eight letters, license plates, domain names and email addresses begin to appear. If a seven letter string is found, it will be difficult to match or beat.
NOTE: an eight letter string will always beat a nine letter string, but a 200 point 8 letter string will beat a 100 point 8 letter string.
NOTE: If Google automatically redirects, such as in the case of
*Alpha, X-ray, Echo, Quebec, Echo, Echo, Echo, Echo* (Credit: Glorfindel)
but there are no results for the actual string, it is accepted.

```
Leaderboard

1. Alpha, X-ray, Echo, Quebec, Echo, Echo, Echo, Echo - 330 points - Glorfindel
2. Echo, Bravo, Quebec, Echo, Tango, X-ray, Echo, Alpha - 262 points
2.
3.
4.
5.
```

Comment: It's the objective a large or small score? The most frequently used letters score less, so a bunch  of xzjq.. will have a lower score than anything containing an e. And a long word with lots of high scoring letters will score higher than a short word.

Comment: The goal is to find the shortest string possible whilst using the most frequent letters. An eight letter string scoring 100 is superior to a nine letter string scoring 400. An eight letter string scoring 200, would be superior to an eight letter string scoring 100. Thank you for pointing out my vagueness!

Comment: This is a game, not a puzzle: it fits exactly the type of question that was disallowed in [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles). Additionally, answers will change over time. For these reasons, it is off-topic for this site.

Comment: (Also, it depends on a single outside resource, which is strongly discouraged: if the single outside resource changes or is lost, the question will no longer be answerable. See the comments [in this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6780/is-it-ok-to-use-specific-users-as-part-of-a-puzzle-mechanism/6783#6783) for details.)

Comment: Darn, now I'm unable to post my 366-point answer (but [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VAkG.png)).

Answer (score 1):

The following query is worth 330 points:

> Alpha X-ray Echo Quebec Echo Echo Echo Echo ([proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpzrB.png))

Comment: @JMP please don't do that, it could turn this page into a search result, invalidating it.

Comment: @JMP huh, that's weird. This is what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpzrB.png

Comment: Just spotted I used Bing!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query worth 360 points:

> Zulu Romeo Tango Echo Echo Echo Echo Echo

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer with [proof](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22zreeaeee%22).

> Zulu Romeo Echo Echo Alpha Echo Echo Echo ->  368 points

and 7 letters is impossible since this webpage has all possible outcomes listed on google.com

> [image]